# Loop through a directory and generate a page of embedded HTML5 videos

Tags: php

Using PHP, how do I recursively loop through a directory of mp4 files and convert the output to produce a page containing embedded HTML5 videos?

The PHP code that I'm working with is:

```
$files = scandir('folder/');
foreach($files as $file) {
  //do your work here
}
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intent is to simply mix the PHP logic and HTML together than the code is simply:

```
$files = scandir('folder/');
foreach($files as $file) {
    echo '<video width="400" controls>
        <source src="' . basename( $file ) . '" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>';
}
```

Although I find it cleaner to have the logic in a separate file and do it like this:

```
<?php foreach($files as $file) { ?>

   <video width="400" controls>
        <source src="<?=basename( $file )?>" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>

<?php } ?>
```

However both are valid and only preference.

Keep in mind of the security of this issue. For example if a different file is in this directory, this could cause a security issue.

Comment: The loop works ok, but the MP4s are not showing. Its only shows the controls.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible

so the code will be something like this:

```
<?php
$videodir = opendir('video_directory');
while(false !== ($filename = readdir($videodir))){
    echo '
        <video width="400" controls>
        <source src="video_directory/'.$filename.'" type="video/mp4">
                 Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
        </video>'
}


?>
```

Comment: why you should do everyone every right on the folder?

Comment: personally I have never tried without 777 permissions but so maybe it will work without permissions too so try it and you will now personally I am always ding with 777 to get rid of headache which can possibly accrue

Comment: it will work with just 644 and ownership to the user the webserver runs under. other users that are not the one of the webserver shouldn't have access to the filesystem. 777 means that any user can do anything: you should only read and eventually write->thus 6 and the other should not even read: thus 4

Comment: please amend your answer, you are posing a severe security issue with your sentence